# Need table captions and list of tables in Arabic, not roman numeral in Word 2010

Tags: microsoft-word-2010, numbering, caption, chapters

I presently have Word 2010 properly incrementing chapter numbers using multilevel lists.  When I insert a table and caption it, it is properly named, i.e. Table Chapter#.Table#.

The problem is that because I have the chapters being numbered using roman numerals, the Chapter# in the table caption is also coming out with roman numerals.

Is there a way to leave the chapter headings in roman numerals and table captions Arabic?